# justify-content: space-between не работает, если текст не помещается в одну строку

Tags: css, bootstrap, flexbox

justify-content: space-between не работает, если текст не помещается в одну строку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Явно добавить отступ между блоками. Причём в данном случае скорее всего `space-between` в принципе плохая идея.

Comment: Что если сделать `text-align: right`?

Comment: text-align: right для правого блока помогло. Благодарю!

Comment: А, ну и `space-between` не применяется потому что нет никакого *space*. Второй блок сначала занял всё свободное пространство и только потом стал переносить слова. Но занятое пространство уже не отдал.

Comment: Задайте блоку с большим текстом другой цвет фона и вы увидите. что никакого space-between не получается, оба блока в строке вплотную. Можно задать margin-left, но тогда текст ещё больше сожмётся. Тут с вёрсткой и макетом надо бы поработать.